# Hide WooCommerce Product Meta (SKU, Categories, Tags) For Specific Pages Using Wordpress Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

You might also be asking: How do I trigger/define a WooCommerce action/function using WordPress Custom Fields?

Using WooCommerce and Wordpress, I've finished making a system whereby I can remove the product meta but only on certain product pages, and I need to define which pages are to have their product meta hidden using wordpress custom fields. **The custom field name I want to call:** 'hide_product_meta' and the defining **values** need to be either '1' or '0' for yes or no.

**To be hidden:**
[image]

I first had a go at creating a filter to do it. I've since edited this post to include the suggestion that lakshman rajput commented below.

This code hides the product meta on pages with a pre-created custom field called 'hide_product_meta' which you can add manually. Define a '1' in the custom field to trigger the code, or anything else to turn it off:

```
/* WooCommerce hide product page meta - hide_product_meta */
function hide_product_page_meta() {
        global $post;
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        $HideProductMetaValue =  get_post_meta($product_id,'hide_product_meta',true);
        if (strpos($HideProductMetaValue, '1') !== false) {
        return remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );
        }
}       
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','hide_product_page_meta');
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would love if someone could help me further with this question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lakshman rajput's help, I managed to get it to work using the following code, but instead of defining the action with 'yes' or 'no', I can define it with '1', like this:

```
/* WooCommerce hide product page meta - hide_product_meta */
function hide_product_page_meta() {
        global $post;
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        $HideProductMetaValue =  get_post_meta($product_id,'hide_product_meta',true);
        if (strpos($HideProductMetaValue, '1') !== false) {
        return remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );
        }
}       
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','hide_product_page_meta');
```